# Dispatch CustomEvent() to prefwindow - Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

Working with a Firefox addon, I wish to send a [CustomEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) to a [preference window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/prefwindow).

I open the preference window using an [openDialog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.openDialog), and keep a reference to the opened window. After that, I try to dispatch the event, but the event is never received.

```
var pWin = window.openDialg("chrome://myextension/path/options.xul", "name", features); 
var event = new pWin.CustomEvent("prefwindow-event"); 
pWin.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In the prefwindow scope, I have this code in the XUL attached script :

```
window.addEventListener("prefwindow-event", this.catchEvent, false);
```

However, I never receive that event. The documentation for CustomEvent() says

> When creating a CustomEvent object, you must create the object from
>   the same window as you're going to fire against.

So does it mean that, I can never dispatch an event from my main extension scope to that of another window ? If this is indeed possible, what am I doing wrong here ? If not, is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following will work

```js
var pWin = window.openDialg("chrome://myextension/path/options.xul", "name", features); 
pWin.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var event = new pWin.CustomEvent("prefwindow-event"); 
  pWin.dispatchEvent(event);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either. If I put my event listener in the same code scope it works, but not within the prefwindow. Besides, as per MDN `createEvent` is  deprecated, and should use CustomEvent instead.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of `createEvent`'s deprecation. But now I'm almost sure I found the problem. Check the revised answer.

Comment: That looks like an interesting hack, but unfortunately I still don't receive the event. I think this is what's explained at MDN "
When creating a CustomEvent object, you must create the object from the same window as you're going to fire against.". 
Another thing, if I am to do the event dispatch from inside a load handler, that would defeat the purpose of the event. Since I intend to send several events to an already loaded window, and not just at the time of load.

Comment: That's what paa's code is doing he's making the window create and dispatch event to itself. it's gotta be an issue with how you're adding event listener than.

Comment: Guys, Thanks for all the inputs! Yes, that would indeed work. +1. But there is a non-standard 'twist' in my addon that it opens preferences window in a tab. A tab supports event listeners and `dispatchEvent` just like a normal window. But `CustomEvent` is not inherited it seems, and I don't get the event. Any ways, I will figure out a way to pass data. I will mark this as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: We can still help you dude. If the window is within a tab then you have to go new `new gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.CustomEvent` and then in your addEventListener, add in a 4th argument of true. so like `addEventListener('prefwindow-event', myfunc, false, true)`

Comment: @Noitidart : yes, I had tried playing around with addEventListener parameters. Wasn't helping me either. Since I think I asked this question for a window, and for your convenience, I raised a new one here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556002/customevent-to-an-xul-tab-firefox-addon

Answer (score 1):

Paa's code should work.

```
var pWin = window.openDialg("chrome://myextension/path/options.xul", "name", features); 
pWin.addEventListener("prefwindow-event", function(){pWin.alert('prefwindow-event fired')}, false);
pWin.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var event = new pWin.CustomEvent("prefwindow-event"); 
  pWin.dispatchEvent(event);
}, false);
```

if not then try this:

```
var pWin = window.openDialg("chrome://myextension/path/options.xul", "name", features); 
pWin.addEventListener("load", function(){
  pWin.addEventListener("prefwindow-event", function(){pWin.alert('prefwindow-event fired')}, false);
  var event = new pWin.CustomEvent("prefwindow-event"); 
  pWin.dispatchEvent(event);
}, false);
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. +1. Please see my comments for the answer.