# CustomEvent() to an XUL tab - Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

For many reasons, I have to open up XUL in a tab, instead of using a standard window. I wish to send [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) to this tab, and here's how my code looks like :

myextension.js :

```
  .. 
  var pTab = window.gBrowser.loadOneTab("chrome://myextension/path/options.xul", 
                  {inBackground: false});
  var pWin = window; 
  var event = new pWin.CustomEvent("prefwindow-event");
  pWin.dispatchEvent(event);
  ..
```

options.xul code:

```
 window.addEventListener("load", init, false); 
 window.addEventListener("prefwindow-event", myevent, false, true);
 .. 
 myevent: function(e) {
      dump("My event : " + e.details ); 
 },
 ..
```

However, I don't get the event. I have tried all possible options. Enabled/Disabled [`useCapture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Syntax) and `wantsUntrusted` of addEventListener(). After realizing that there are restrictions in sending custom events between windows, I also tried dispatching event with the tab element, like this :

```
pTab.dispatchEvent(event);
```

That wouldn't work either. 1) The event dispatch would work [perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502868/dispatch-customevent-to-prefwindow-firefox-addon) if I use a dialog window instead of a tab (`openDialog` instead of `loadOneTab`). 2) The tab element [only inherits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tab#Methods) `dispatchEvent` and not a `CustomEvent`

So the question is, is there a way to send custom events and have it received in a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var event = new pTab.linkedBrowser._contentWindow.CustomEvent("prefwindow-event");
```

edit:

Proof of concept, open scratchpad, switch environment to browser, run the following snippet

```
var url = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,';
var content = '<html><script>addEventListener("Hello",function(){alert("Hello")},false)</script></html>'
var tab  = gBrowser.loadOneTab(url+encodeURIComponent(content), {inBackground: false});

tab.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var evt = new tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.CustomEvent("Hello");
  tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, false);
```

Comment: Nope. Tried that just now. Doesn't work. Also, isn't `pWin` and `pTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow` referring the same window ?

Comment: `pTab.linkedBrowser._contentWindow` is the window that hosts `chrome://myextension/path/options.xul`. Again, it is important to wait until the `load` event is fired. If you do, it works

Comment: Great, Thanks. It was a misunderstanding from my end that `pWin` and `pTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow` were the same. But now I have a small problem. The part of the code which sends the event is entered quite frequently to send the event. So, I do a `removeEventListener` inside the 'load' event handler to make it only run once. But in that case I don't receive the first dispatched event. I do receive the later events, but not the first. Any idea why ? You can quickly test in scratchpad by naming that function and doing a `tab.removeEventListener("load", runOnce, false)`.